# URL with special characters is not working

Tags: url

I am trying to open .pdf file in IE7 and firefox, but its not working.

Actually yhere is a hyperlink on HTML page on That Hyperlink click event i m opening .PDF file

Problem with file name when i used to open file **D:\Documents\Doc\Trans1\1\Pages from 818 averill avenue 1_001-5.pdf** its working fine in all browsers but when i tried to open file **D:\Documents\Doc\Trans1\1\Pages from 818 averill avenue #1_001-5.pdf** i get error, page not found in IE7 and Firefox and in IE6 its working fine. Only change in that is added **#** in file name.

Why does the file not open?

Comment: How is this Programming related? Voted to close until question is edited with relevant info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your back slashes to forward slashes and add "file:///" to the front. Then URL encode the hash (# is %23).

Answer (score 1):

A # in a URL denotes a named anchor.

I can't reproduce your error with FF3. Both dragging from Explorer and opening via File|Open manage to display a PDF inside FF when the filename contains a hash

Comment: Actualy There is Hyperlink on HTML page on That Hyperlink click event i m opening .PDF file

Comment: you need to replace # with %23 in the hyperlink href value.